# Concatenate/Append many dataframes in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, append, concatenation

I have a list of dataframes df1 to df20 that are being created from a loop and I need to concatenate all of them in one go. These dataframes are dynamic and can be any number between 1 to 20 as per the loop that generates in my code.

So, I was trying to create an empty list first and add these dataframe names to it (in a loop for 1 to 20 as example) and to use this list in pd.concat(df_list) as below:

```
df_list=[]
for in in range(1,21):
    df_list.append(f'df{i}')

pd.concat(df_list)
```

the above code is creating list of dataframe names but in the form of string with quotes like below and I'm unable to concatenate the dataframes using the pd.concat(df_list) as it's considering all the dataframe names as string elements

```
print(df_list)

['df1', 'df2', 'df3', 'df4', 'df5', 'df6', 'df7', 'df8', 'df9', 'df10', 'df11', 'df12', 'df13', 'df14', 'df15', 'df16', 'df17', 'df18','df19','df20']
```

Appreciate if anyone can help me in getting this concatenation of dataframes.

I think if I can add the dataframes names without quotes, like df_list=[df0,df1,df2...] then the pd.concat can work or else please let me know if there is any best alternative to get this done. Thanks!

**UPDATE**
As per commented suggestions, I've created a simple loop to create multiple dataframes and then I tried to append the "names of these dataframes" to an empty list in this loop itself where these dataframes are getting created. But, the o/p is not what am I expecting.

```
mylist=[]
for x in range(1,4):
    globals()[f"df{i}"]=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(99,size=(3,3)),columns=['AA','BB','CC'])
    mylist.append(globals()[f"df{i}"])
```

The above code creates 3 dataframes df1,df2 and df3 and also the empty list is getting appended but with the contents of dataframes as shown below

```
print(mylist)
[   AA  BB  CC
0  57  92  50
1  33  47  28
2  82  77  46,    AA  BB  CC
0  18   8  75
1   1  15  52
2   4  69  38,    AA  BB  CC
0  19  24  31
1  24  52  62
2  50   8  63]
```

But, my desired output is not the contents of the dataframes, but the names of the dataframes themselves like below.

```
print(mylist)
[df1,df2,df3]
```

Appreciate if anyone can show me how to get this done. I think there must be some simple way to do this.

Comment: You should populate the list during the loop that creates the DataFrames, that way you don't have 1-20 random variables floating around. If you want to reference them by some feature/name, then you can use a `dict` where the keys are that label as opposed to the list index.

Comment: what you want to do is capture them in a list when they are generated, then concat that list.  Its generally bad practice to refer to vars by their string representation

Comment: @ALollz can you please show by example as what you were suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're efectively appending strings to your list. If you have named variables, `df1` to `df20`, you can access them by using `locals()` (or `globals()` depending on where your named variables are, and if you are concatenating the dataframes in a function or not). Here is an example,

```
df1 = 0
df2 = 1
df3 = 2

df_list = []
for i in range(1, 4):
    df_list.append(locals()[f'df{i}'])

>>> df_list
    [0, 1, 2]
```

**EDIT**: I think what you want to do is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

mylist = []
for x in range(1, 4):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(99, size=(3,3)), columns=['AA','BB','CC'])
    mylist.append(df)
    
dfs = pd.concat(mylist)
```

Note that printing `mylist` is never going to tell you something along the lines of `mylist = [df1, df2, df3]`, even if you hardcode that. That will print the entire content of all the variables inside your list. If you don't know how many dataframes you're going to concatenate for some reason, then just implement a `while` loop that `break`s when you want to stop creating dataframes.

Consider another example

```
# create a list of 100 dataframes (df0 to df99)
mylist = []
for x in range(100):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(99,size=(3,3)), columns=['AA','BB','CC'])
    mylist.append(df)

concat_range = input("Range of dataframes to concatenate (0-100): ")
i, j = concat_range.split(" ")

dfs = pd.concat(mylist[int(i) : int(j)])

# further operations on dfs
```

Now, let's say I am the user and I want to concatenate `df5` to `df32`.

```
>>> Range of dataframes to concatenate (0-100): 5 32
>>> dfs
    AA  BB  CC
    0   28  37  36
    1   34  18  14
    2   39  41  97
    0   44  66  76
    1   57  16   3
    ..  ..  ..  ..
    1   43  87  74
    2   67  70  73
    0   40  60  57
    1   23  63  70
    2   96  24  31
    
    [81 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks @Camilo Martinez: But, df1,df2,df3.....these are my dataframes and I don't have any values assigned as you've shown. What I need is to concatenate all these dataframes themselves based on how many they are created from a loop. So, they can be df1,df2..df5 or upto df10 or df20 and I want to concatenate all of them in one go like pd.concat([df1,df2,df3,df4....]) but without hard coding as I don't know how many they can be.

Comment: If you are already creating them in a loop, what stops you from appending each one of them to a list when they're being created? In general, avoid named variables like these, when you could be using Python's data structures like a list, a tuple or a dictionary.

Comment: I've tried as you suggested(I think) and updated the post with the actual o/p vs expected o/p. Appreciate if you can look at it and help in fixing it as what am I doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: There is no need to have a list that, when printed, shows you the variables inside, only showing their name as if you were coding it. Please, see my updated answer.